# Trigger a function during onload

Tags: javascript

I recently added Javascript and CSS files into the wordpress. All the files are being registered through `functions.php`. One of the files is `my_worldmap.js` as shown below

```
$(function() {
    $('#world-map').vectorMap();
});
```

The issue here, the above function is called as soon as I visit the homepage. My expectation that the code is only called when I visit `www.mydomain.com/global-network`. How can I do this in WordPress ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enqueue your script only when the page you want it on is requested:

```
function wpa_script() {
    if( is_page( 'global-network' ) ){
        wp_enqueue_script(
            'wpa_script',
            get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/my_worldmap.js',
            array('jquery')
        );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpa_script' );
```

See [`is_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page) in Codex.

Comment: The url is `http://www.mydomain.com/newsite/#/438/global-network-2`. I tried with is_page(438) but my js is not called. Any idea ?

Comment: that permalink looks strange, I'll guess your theme is loading pages via ajax & custom queries. it's difficult to say without seeing the theme code, you may need to ask the theme's developer how you can target a specific page load.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using wordpress inbuilt jQuery then you should replace your $ sign with jQuery.
it should be like this.

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('#world-map').vectorMap();
});
```

This should help you.

Comment: I don't see how this changes anything. As I mentioned that the code should run only when I click on a certain page, e.g "Global Map" page

Comment: Have you tried to debug in firebug in firefox. What it is showing there. This might help you.

Comment: There's no error my friend. It's just the function is called when I visit my homepage, e.g `www.mydomain.com`. My expectation that the code is only called when I visit `www.mydomain.com/global-network`. How can I do this in WordPress ?

Comment: I think milo has just answered your question. I didn't get your question in first place. Now its clear.